# Expression in R

Tags: r, expression

I want to use `expression` for my `ylab=` when plotting in R. How do I get characters, using `expression` using the [\mathcal{}](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Symbols:%5Cmathcal) style font? I am running Ubuntu and I don't want to use ggplot.

To clarify: part of the `ylab` will contain mathcal characters and part of it will not (and will be a formula). That's why I want to use `expression`
It is this symbol which I want:
[image] = \mathcal{E}

Comment: Coul you show us the knid of label you would like to have, [e.g., with this online tool](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php) ?

Comment: Would  [`tikzDevice`](http://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/tikzdevice/) be a possible solution or is it too complicated for your purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to use `tikz`, which is kind of awesome, here is a much less beautiful example than the one they generate in the help of function `tikzDevide::tikz`:

```
require(filehash)
require(tikzDevice)

tikz("sinhplot.tex", width = 8, height = 4, 
     standAlone = TRUE,
     packages = c("\\usepackage{tikz}",
                  "\\usepackage[active,tightpage,psfixbb]{preview}",
                  "\\PreviewEnvironment{pgfpicture}",
                  "\\setlength\\PreviewBorder{0pt}",
                  "\\usepackage{amssymb}")
plot(sinh, col="steelblue", lwd=2, xlim=c(-3,3), xlab="$\\mathcal E= [-3 , 3]$")
grid()
dev.off()

tools::texi2dvi(sinhplot,pdf=T)
system(paste(getOption('pdfviewer'),'sinhplot.pdf'))
```

The result looks quite nice!
[image]

Another solution is to just give up having beautiful characters in the labels of your figures...